# Can we add the suffix ne to hortatory/jussive subjunctive?

Tags: grammar-choice

The [Hortatory Subjunctive](https://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/hortatory-subjunctive) in the first person is a polite way to urge/ask someone to do something: *eamus*: let's go!.

I wonder if it is possible to add *-ne* to this subjunctive creating even-weaker command - which is basically a suggestion. *eamus**ne**?* = would we go now?/ are you ready?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Eamusne* – and more generally direct questions in the present subjunctive, in particular in first person – will generally be understood as the [deliberative or dubitative subjunctive](https://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/deliberative-subjunctive) (*coniunctivus deliberativus/dubitativus*). This type of subjunctive is called so because the speaker is weighing his options, or wondering if he should take a certain course of action or not. So

> **Eamusne?**

translates to:

> **Should we go?**

(I guess *Eamus an non?* can probably have a hortatory undertone, like asking “Are we going or not?” in English, but in general it is an open question.)

Often the deliberative subjunctive can take on a polemical character, especially in the past (imperfect subjunctive), e.g. *Quid facerem?* can, depending on context, be translated as “What was I to do?” or as “What was I supposed to do?”

Comment: What I find interesting is that there is no attestation for *eamusne* in PHI. The only place we get -iamusne is in a -ne...an construction, and looking through -amusne and -emusne I don't see a plethora of subjunctives that fit the bill.

Comment: @cmw but note A&G's example *Etiamne eam salūtem?* from Plautus.

Comment: I found another with Pliny *NH*: *dubitemusne*. First person, plural, subjunctive + ne still seems surprisingly rare, and nothing that that I see would constitute hortatory over deliberative.